# Are moderators able to post comments that are automatically deleted after x amount of time?

Tags: support, comments, moderators, auto-delete

[This comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127918/why-cant-i-harvest-blood-for-discerning-the-transmundane#comment174767_127918) reads the following:

> If you're looking for the previous 33 comments, please see this meta thread instead. This comment will self-destruct in 48 hours. – Raven Dreamer♦

(The link inside the comment is not included as it is not relevant.)

The claim that the comment will self-destruct in 48 hours is the subject of this question.  Are moderators able to post comments that are automatically deleted after *x* amount of time?

Comment: I think the mod's just going to come back in 48 hours and press the red X.

Comment: This comment will self-destruct in 365,317,430,675,889.42 minutes.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I will be back in 695 048 384 years to check on that.

Comment: also; who's gonna be there in 39 hours to make sure RD follows through?

Comment: @michaelb958 Your math skills are impressive! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber [I doubt that](https://www.google.com/search?q=365%2C317%2C430%2C675%2C889.42+minutes+in+years&oq=365%2C317%2C430%2C675%2C889.42+minutes+in+years&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0j69i62.1795j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @AndrewBarber No, my command of Python 2.7 is impressive. (And my math skills. But Python did the heavy lifting.)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Andrew's comment is now the second search result!

Comment: @michael when I originally did the search, it was the first result (for me, at least).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, we can't. We just sometimes say that to mean we will come back and delete it soon.

I think the general reason we might tend to do this is that we are sensitive about leaving 'meta' comments around, but there are things where we think it's useful to do so. That particular comment seems to be a perfect example. Saying the comment will be deleted is sort of a disclaimer saying, "this is a meta comment and shouldn't usually be made, so I'm going to delete it soon".

Now, this reminds me to check if I have any of those pending...